# Prove that every element $a$ of a C*-algebra $A$ is a finite linear combination of unitary elements of $A$

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Prove that every element $a$ of a C*-algebra $A$ is a finite linear combination of unitary elements of $A$.

I have no idea to figure it out, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: If $a\in A$ is self-adjoint and $\|a\|\leq1$, then $0\leq1-a^2$ and $a+i\sqrt{1-a^2}$ is a unitary such that
\begin{align}
a&=\frac{1}{2}\left(a+i\sqrt{1-a^2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(a-i\sqrt{1-a^2}\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(a+i\sqrt{1-a^2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(a+i\sqrt{1-a^2}\right)^*.
\end{align}
Thus by rescaling, any self-adjoint in $A$ can be written as a linear combination of two unitaries.  Since any element of $A$ is a linear combination of two self-adjoints, we know...

Comment: Aweygan could you please elaborate it please :)

Comment: Could whoever downvoted please elaborate?

Comment: Thanks Aweygan for the hint :) :)

Comment: Dear @Aweygan, can you explain what $a + i \sqrt{1-a^2}$ is unitary?

Comment: Dear @Parisa, could you help me out telling me why is $a+i\sqrt{1-a^2}$ unitary? I am not sure what  $[\sqrt{1-a^2}]^*$ looks like.

Comment: @Sarah As $1-a^2$ is self-adjoint, $\sqrt{1-a^2}$ is also self-adjoint, and $(a+i\sqrt{1-a^2})^*=a-i\sqrt{1-a^2}$.  Can you see now that $a+i\sqrt{1-a^2}$ is unitary?

Comment: Dear @Aweygan ok, from there I can see it, thank you. But I would like to ask you: what about if $1-a^2$ was unitary for instance? Would if follow that its square root is also unitary? Or in general, is it true for any function that is continous on the spectrum of $a$?